# Create new channel using bot in telegram or telegram api

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

How can I create new channenl using a bot in Telegram or telegram api?

I used lib 'telegram-mtproto'. And method i used 'channels.createChannel' in https://core.telegram.org/methods Here is my code

```
import MTProto from 'telegram-mtproto'

const api = {
    layer: 57,
    // initConnection: 0x69796de9,
    api_id: 1153141
}

const server = {
    dev: true //We will connect to the test server.
} //Any empty configurations fields can just not be specified

const client = MTProto({ server, api })

export const connect = async () => {
    const result = await client('channels.createChannel', {
        title: 'This is title',
        about: 'This is description',
        address: 't.me/test123456'
    })
    console.log('TCL: result', result)
}
```

and i get this

```
Error 401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED 2 2
(node:14408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED CODE#401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED
```

Can't anyone help me for this or give me an idea. thanks you so much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Users can create new group or channel in telegram